# database table have html,js content which dispaly on textarea

Tags: php

my database table value contain php/js/html like this

```
<h2>Welcome</h2> <p> &nbsp;&nbsp;test</p>
```

which can display on textarea,but not replacing any html,js

Comment: Like what exactly? and whats your problem/question

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Can you be more precise about what you're trying to achieve, what you tried, and why it didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

As the question is a little unclear this may or may not be what was intended - but I interpreted the question to mean "How can I display text from database in a textarea without replacing anything?"

To that end `htmlentities` or `htmlspecialchars` should be of use.

```
$str='<h2>Welcome</h2> <p> &nbsp;&nbsp;test</p>';
printf( "<textarea cols=80 rows=10>%s</textarea>", htmlentities( $str, ENT_COMPAT ) );
```